# Can not create an instance of Preloadjs

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

I gave a problem with creating an instance of PreloadJS.
I want to preload some images for my HTML5 game so I did it like this:

```
this.preloader = new createjs.PreloadJS();
```

The compiler says that

> undefined is not a function.

I included the libraries in the main html page like this:

```
<script src="libraries/PreloadJS-release_v0.4.0/lib/preloadjs-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Could the other librari from easeljs cause a problem because I have this also included :

```
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: I found another possibility to create a preloader with PreloadJS. This kind of version I posten in my question is old I think.
So you have to use a LoadQueue like this:
**this.preloader = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@deLuna is correct:

PreloadJS changed the main class name in version 3.0 to "LoadQueue", which makes more sense. SoundJS was also changed to "Sound" at the same time.

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of preloadjs the instance method await a boolean parameter :

```
     /**
     * PreloadJS provides a consistent way to preload content for use in HTML applications.
     * @class PreloadJS
     * @param Boolean useXHR2 Determines whether the preload instance will use XmlHttpRequests, or fall back on tag loading.
     * @constructor
     * @extends AbstractLoader
     */
var PreloadJS = function(useXHR2) {
        this.initialize(useXHR2);
    };
```

Try:

```
this.preloader = new createjs.PreloadJS(false);
```

or

```
this.preloader = new createjs.PreloadJS(true);
```

Source of documentation:

[preloadjs documentation](http://docs.createjs.jp/PreloadJS_docs-0.1.0/PreloadJS.js.html)

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question!
I used your example but now I get another error that is saying
"object is not a function".
I think I am stuck at this error.

Comment: The Japanese documentation is still referencing earlier versions. Check out http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS for the latest.